# ajax post , but I'm unable to receive data on the server

Tags: ajax, node.js

I have a form in jade , I'm posting form ajax way , there is not problem in ajax method but I'm unable to receive data on the server. Please help me solve this.Previously I have never come across this.

jade

```
form(accept-charset="UTF-8", action="/booking/get/trips", name="gettrips", method="post", enctype='multipart/form-data', id="gettrips")
      p
        label(for='from') From
        select#from(name="fromCity", required="required")
          each fromcity in cities
            option(value="#{fromcity.cityId}") #{fromcity.cityName}
      p.destination
        label(for='to') To
        select#to(name="toCity", required="required")
          option select

      p
        label(for='datetimepicker') Depart
        input#datetimepicker(type='text', name="departDate", value='2014-03-15')

      p.mr-0
        label(for='datetimepicker1')
          input#chk(type='checkbox', name="returnDate", value='', checked='checked')
          | Return
        input#datetimepicker1(type='text', value='2014-03-15')
      p
        button(type="submit", value="find") look
```

booking.js

```
getTrips: function getTrips(req, res, next){

    var options = {
      fromCity :req.body.fromCity,
      toCity   : req.body.toCity,
      departDate : req.body.departDate
    };
    console.log('date ' + req.body.departDate); // undefined

    if (req.body.returndate) {
      options.returnDate = req.body.returnDate; 
    }

    console.log('got form info ' + JSON.stringify(options));  //gives null
  },
```

js

```
function getTrips() {
  var lookup = $('#gettrips');
  lookup.submit(function (ev) {
      $.ajax({
          type: lookup.attr('method'),
          url: lookup.attr('action'),
          data: lookup.serialize(),
          success: function (data) {
            //ok  send response
          }
      });
      ev.preventDefault();
  });
}
```

route

```
var booking = require('./booking');

module.exports = function (app) {
  app.post('/booking/get/trips', booking.collectTripsInfo, booking.validateTripInfo, };
```

Comment: Is this an Express-based app?  If so, can you show your router?

Comment: updated route in question

Comment: What do you see on the server?  Does it 404?  Does it get to your route handler, but `req.body` isn't populated?

Comment: What do you see in the network traffic of your browser's web tools ?

Comment: yes req.body doesnt seem to populate.

I have  express.urlencoded() and express.json() inuse, when I switch to bodyparser() it works tho.